# How to separate overlapping portraits in an image?

Tags: image-processing

Assume that I have an image with overlapping portraits. Here is an example of mandala-portraits arranged in a random star-graph:

[image]

I want to separate the overlapping portraits and, say, estimate their areas. Here is an example of *partially* successful separation:

[image]

(4, 9, and 10 are not separated.)

I can manually edit the overlapping portraits:

[image]

[image]

What would be the non-manual editing solution?

Also, I would appreciate any simplifications of the partially successful separation code. (See below.)

---

### Image generation

The mandala-portraits image was generated with the code:

```
SeedRandom[80];
lsPolys = 
  Map[Polygon[
     Sort[
       PolygonCoordinates[
        Rectangle[#, # + RandomInteger[{12, 16}, 2]]]][[{1, 3, 4, 2}]]] &, RandomInteger[{0, 120}, {16, 2}]];
grPolys0 = Graphics[lsPolys, ImageSize -> 400]; grPolys = 
 ResourceFunction["TexturizePolygons"][lsPolys, Random, 
  "ColorFunction" -> "DarkRainbow", "Radius" -> Sqrt[{6, 4, 2}], 
  "ConnectingFunction" -> FilledCurve@*BezierCurve, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.78]];
lsCenters = Mean@*PolygonCoordinates /@ lsPolys;
center = First@TakeSmallestBy[lsCenters, Norm[# - Mean[lsCenters]] &, 1];
grLines = 
 Graphics[
  Map[{Thickness[RandomReal[{0.001, 0.006}]], Line[{center, #}]} &, 
   Complement[lsCenters, center]]]; img = 
 Image@Show[{grLines, grPolys}, 
   Background -> Nest[Lighter, LightBlue, 6], ImageSize -> 800]
```

---

### Sub-images separation

The partially successful separation was done with this code:

```
imgBin0 = Binarize[img, 0.8]
imgBin1 = Dilation[imgBin0, 2.5]
imgMod = ConstantArray[0, ImageDimensions[imgBin1]];
Do[imgMod[[686 + i, 442 + j]] = 1, {i, -2, 2}, {j, -20, 20}]
imgBin1a = ImageAdd[imgBin1, Image[imgMod]];
Grid[{{"Original", "Edited"}, 
  Show[#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {imgBin1, imgBin1a}}, Dividers -> All]
imgBin2 = ColorNegate@imgBin1a;
lsRectangleArrray = MorphologicalComponents[imgBin2];
lsRectangleArrray1 = Reverse[lsRectangleArrray];
Colorize[lsRectangleArrray]
lsInds = Rest@Union@Flatten@lsRectangleArrray;
aSizes = 
  Association[
   Rule @@@ DeleteCases[Tally[Flatten@lsRectangleArrray1], {0, _}]];
aSizes = KeySelect[aSizes, aSizes[#] > 1000 &];
aRectangles = 
  Association@
   Map[# -> (Transpose[{MinMax[#[[All, 1]]], MinMax[#[[All, 2]]]}] &@
        Position[lsRectangleArrray, #]) &, lsInds];
aRectangles1 = 
  Association@
   Map[# -> (Transpose[{MinMax[#[[All, 2]]], MinMax[#[[All, 1]]]}] &@
        Position[lsRectangleArrray1, #]) &, lsInds];
aSubImages = 
 ImageTake[img, Sequence @@ Transpose[#]] & /@ 
  KeyTake[aRectangles, Keys[aSizes]]
HighlightImage[img, Rectangle @@@ KeyTake[aRectangles1, Keys[aSizes]],
  ImageSize -> All, ImagePadding -> 30, PlotLabel -> "Sub-images"]
```